# C++ : Memory overhead due to virtuality?

Tags: c++, memory, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ virtual function table memory cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626290/c-virtual-function-table-memory-cost)

I've juste read that : http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html and I wonder what is the memory overhead due to virtuality.
I'm currently writing an optimized code for supercomputers, and I have to find the good balance between a readable code and memory consumption.

In order to understand how it works what would be the memory overhead for the following classes :

```
class AbstractA {/* SOMETHING */};
class AbstractB {/* SOMETHING */};
class A : public AbstractA {/* SOMETHING */};
class B : public AbstractB {/* SOMETHING */};
class A2 : public A {/* SOMETHING */};
class B2 : public B {/* SOMETHING */};
class AbstractAB : public AbstractA, public AbstractB {/* SOMETHING */};
class AbstractAB2 : public AbstractAB {/* SOMETHING */};
```

Suppose that I have one billion objects of each class, I have to bother about non-static memory consumption. So how much will it be for each object type ? (if each virtual method of AbstractA will create a pointer for each object of type "A", I die...)

Comment: The `sizeof()` operator is there for a reason.

Comment: @Mystical: That only tells you the per-object cost. There's typically a per-class cost too.

Comment: @MikeSeymour If he's got a billion instances of each class, any per-class cost is gonna be negligible to the per-object cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might wanna look at Item 24 of Scott Meyer's [More Effective C++](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/more-effective-c/9780321545190/). It is titled 'Understand the costs of virtual functions, multiple inheritance, virtual base class and RTTI '. In this item Meyers goes over the overhead involved in making use of these facilities.

Comment: I *might* want to look at something you didn't even give me motivation to read? What's in Item 24 that the rest of should know? Please summarize.

Comment: It's titled "Understand the costs of virtual functions, multiple inheritance, virutal base classes, and RTTI". It's 10 pages long, and might provide the insight to what you want to know. Also, as a kind stranger, I'll tell you that you come off as being a bit of a brat. It falls on you to come up with the necessary motivation to look at a suggested source that answers your question.

Comment: @GManNickG I added the title and a one line summary of the item.

Comment: @EXIT_FAILURE: If it were readily available, sure. If I have to purchase a book, wait 3-5 days, and then finally look up what he's referring to just to see what it's about, no. We would call such a remark a comment, not a solution.

Comment: @GManNickG: My reaction was only at the displayed discontent with Sanket's answer. It was lacking in specifics, I agree, but this could've been requested more politely. To me, a serious answer to such a question needs to cover a lot of ground, and is already done by Scott Meyers. I think people would recognize this, and vouch for the book's relevancy to the question (by upvotes), hopefully providing the motivation to read it. Then again, your comment got several upvotes, so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It's implementation-defined, but just about every implementation will use:

- 1 pointer (called a "vptr") per polymorphic object
- 1 static table of function pointers and other RTTI information (called a "vtable") per polymorphic class.

You can use `sizeof` to check the per-object cost, and the per-class cost is probably negligible unless you define a vast number of classes.

Comment: In fact, an object can even have several vptr, when using multiple inheritance.