# Virtual methods memory usage Java vs C++

Tags: java, c++, memory, virtual

**WARNING:** Please keep in mind that this question is plain wrong - it makes a wrong assumption because I have misinterpreted a poorly written tutorial (a book actually) on C++. For case you are curious, this is the original contents:

> In C++ marking a method as virtual causes the objects to use more
>   memory - for every additional virtual method the memory for a pointer
>   (4 - 8 bytes) more.  How does Java deals with this, where all methods
>   by default are virtual?

Comment: Simple question, yet nobody seems to bother even to comment what's wrong with it. I hope that this is not a hate on Java.

Comment: You assumption is wrong. C++ have single table of virtual methods for class not instance.

Comment: First of all, can you give a reference where this is written that " for every additional virtual method the memory for a pointer (4 - 8 bytes) more."

Comment: It's in a book I'm reading.

Comment: Which book you are referring  ?

Comment: Java has a single VFT per class. [Same with C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626290/c-virtual-function-table-memory-cost).

Comment: You've either misunderstood the book, or the book is wrong (perhaps not intentionally, as proofreading is too often left to laymen). Can you provide a quote?

Comment: The book wasn't clear about the fact that C++ has a single table of virtual methods per class not per instance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on faulty assumption on how C++ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic assumption is incorrect. The size of the object does not increase with the number of virtual functions.

If the class has ANY virtual functions then it has a single pointer to a vtable for that class. The size of the object won't change beyond that regardless how many virtual functions:

```
struct s0 {};

struct s1
{
    virtual void f1() {}
};

struct s2
{
    virtual void f1() {}
    virtual void f2() {}
};

struct s3
{
    virtual void f1() {}
    virtual void f2() {}
    virtual void f3() {}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "s0: " << sizeof(s0) << '\n';
    std::cout << "s1: " << sizeof(s1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "s2: " << sizeof(s2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "s3: " << sizeof(s3) << '\n';
}
```

**RESULTS:**

```
s0: 1
s1: 8
s2: 8
s3: 8
```

Comment: I did exactly same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that objects are using more memory? I would say that you are using more space with the virtual function table but not with each object.

Comment: The book I'm reading wasn't clear about this.